# How can I overwrite the default print output of a python dataclass?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Given the `InventoryItem`example from the `dataclasses` documentation.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class InventoryItem:
    """Class for keeping track of an item in inventory."""
    name: str
    unit_price: float
    quantity_on_hand: int = 0

InventoryItem(name="Banana", unit_price=5, quantity_on_hand=3)

# OUTPUT:
# InventoryItem(name='Banana', unit_price=5, quantity_on_hand=3)
```

How to overwrite the standard output message such that the output string

```py
"3 Banana(s) at a unit price of 5."
```

is displayed?

Comment: Did you write and answer your own question at the same time? I am confused 

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Yes. I thought that this is a legit way to add information to stackoverflow that might be missing. But I realized, that my solution doesn't  add value and I wanted to have a behavior that is not Pythonic, therefore, I will delete my answer.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I was confused but now I understand. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, dataclasses are normal classes. There is no such a thing as a dataclass type.

There are two ways to override the standard output message of any Python class:

- define the `__repr__` method

  In [Python's data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) this method is...

  > ... the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value.

  The representation that you want is not a valid expression to recreate the object, so this is not a good choice.
- define the `__str__` method

  Again from the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__):

  > Called by str(object) and the built-in functions format() and print() to compute the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of an object. [...] This method differs from object.__repr__() in that there is no expectation that __str__() return a valid Python expression.

  This is what I would recommend using.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class InventoryItem:
    """Class for keeping track of an item in inventory."""
    name: str
    unit_price: float
    quantity_on_hand: int = 0
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity_on_hand} {self.name}(s) at a unit price of {self.unit_price}"
```

```
>>> item = InventoryItem(name="Banana", unit_price=5, quantity_on_hand=3)
>>> item  # __repr__ being called
InventoryItem(name='Banana', unit_price=5, quantity_on_hand=3)
>>> print(item)  # __str__ being called
3 Banana(s) at a unit price of 5
```